# How should I document a bean that's only supposed to be managed by CDI?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi, javadoc, design-by-contract

Here is my class:

```
@Stateless
@Transactional
public class PostService {
    @Inject private PostRepository postRepo;
    @Inject private UserRepository userRepo;
    @Inject private SectionRepository sectionRepo;
    @Inject private LoggedInUser loggedInUser;

    public PostDto getPost(@PostExists int id){
        Post p = postRepo.findById(id);
        //create post DTO from p
        return post;
    }

    public void delete(@PostExists int id){
        postRepo.remove(postRepo.findById(id));
    }

    public int newPost(@NotBlank @Max(255) String title,
                       @Max(2000) String body,
                       @SectionExists String sectionName){
        User user = userRepo.getByName(loggedInUser.getUsername());
        Section section = sectionRepo.getByName(sectionName);

        Post post = new Post();
        post.setTitle(title);
        post.setContent(body == null || body.isBlank() ? "" : body);
        post.setAuthor(user);
        post.setSection(section);
        post.setType(TEXT);

        return postRepo.insert(post).getId();
    }

}
```

Its annotations (`@NotBlank`, `@Max(255)`, etc.) are processed by a CDI interceptor (to be precise, [BValInterceptor](https://github.com/apache/bval/blob/master/bval-jsr/src/main/java/org/apache/bval/cdi/BValInterceptor.java)) which throws a unchecked exception if there are violated constraints.

I know that Interceptors are supposed to cover *cross-cutting concerns*, but this one tightly couples with my business logic since I wanted to apply *design by contract* methodology for my methods.

With the current setup `PostService` can't be instantiated using `new` as its interceptor wouldn't work and it wouldn't check for parameters correctness. This is fine for me since I'm never supposed to manually instantiate my service classes, but is it a good idea to write a JavaDoc for my bean with the assumption that it will always be instantiated through CDI (and so its interceptor will always be executed)?

Comment: What I do is always use constructor injection. This immediately communicates the fact that this class needs several collaborators to be instantiated. Now, CDI can use package private and/or protected constructors. You can protect your constructor to communicate the intent that this class is not to be instantiated by `new`, thus needs to be instantiated by a framework. Alternatively and still with constructor injection, the constructor is annotated with `@Inject`, again hinting that this class must be instantiated by a framework.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos i thought CDI required a zero-arg public constructor... I'll definitely try out the protected constructor methodology, looks like the best solution